# How to debug multi-threaded Raspberry Pi code executed in qemu

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, raspberry-pi, qemu

I am trying to debug code written for Raspberry Pi on my Ubuntu laptop. I am using:

- the Raspberry Pi Toolchain and (partial ?) root fs obtained with `git clone git://github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git` executed in ~/rpi
- qemu virtualizer installed from Ubuntu repositiories - qemu-arm reports
  version 2.0.0
- the following test case:

  ```
  #include <pthread.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  static void *thread(void *arg)
  {
     static char szReturn[] = "Me too";

     puts((char *)arg);
     puts("Hello, I'm Thread");
     return szReturn;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     pthread_t tid;
     char szGreeting[] = "Hello, I'm Main", *reply;

     if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &thread, szGreeting) != 0)
     {
          perror("pthread_create says: ");
          return 1;
     }
     puts("Nice to meet you");
     if (pthread_join(tid, (void **)&reply) == 0)
          puts(reply);

     return 0;
  }
  ```

After adding `~/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin` to the `PATH` (I am using 64 bit Ubuntu), I do (from the directory in which the test code resides):

- `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -O0 test.c -o test -lpthread`
- `qemu-arm -L ~/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc ./test`

I get the expected output, so the thread creation and execution works.

However, if I do:

- `qemu-arm -g 1234 -L ~/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc ./test` in one terminal, to launch qemu and have it waiting for the debugger to connect to it
- `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb -ex="target remote localhost:1234" -x="set breakpoint pending on" -ex="break main" ./test` in another terminal, to start debugging the program with gdb

I get in gdb, after 'continue' I reach main, I set breakpoints to thread, 21 and 24, I next OK to the ptread_create call, so debugging the main thread works, but:

- when it executes pthread_create, instead of hitting one of the 3 breakpoints (the thread, the create failure or the create success cases), gdb reports "inferior terminated' and the session ends
- back in the qemu terminal though, the program has generated the normal output, so the thread was created and executed, and the whole program worked as expected

So gdb can not debug multithreaded programs in this configuration/setup?! What am I missing?

Could the fact that I am running Ubuntu in a Parallels virtual machine on an OSX machine have something to do with it? I don't have a dedicated Ubuntu machine to test, but I doubt it.

Update: On a native Fedora system the behavior is even worse: the breakpoints are also not taken, but it also crashes in `puts` and `pthread_join`.

Thanks in advance